# How to export an animation from Blender and load it in Unity?

Tags: animation, export, unity, .fbx

My FBX file from Blender (as well as the *.blend* file) comes into Unity with no animation - none of the other forum posts have helped. The animation is very simple - made with keyframes in the dopesheet. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You should bake your animations before exporting to FBX using bake option:

[image]

this option includes all constraints and even any rig which is done in *Animation Nodes* addon.